How to show tier price catalog category view page in configurable product option select simple product in magento 2.4
To display tier prices for configurable products in Magento 2.4, you need to make sure that when a simple product (child product) is selected from the configurable product options, the tier prices for that simple product are correctly displayed product details page
but product list page how to show ?

Category list page

Advance thanks for the help
